# Calculate The Sum of Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a series like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%282%2F%28n*%282n-2m-1%29%29%29%2C%20m%3D0%20to%20%28n-1%29):

$$
  \sum\limits_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac{2}{n(2n - 2m -1)}  
$$

In the end, it should be a function of $n$ only where $m$ should be represented by $n$ somehow, I really cannot remember which series should I use to calculate the result. I imagine this series should converge at least, right? if so, what is the final result.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a finite series, so it definitely converges...

Comment: how do you expect us to calculate the sum of series you never give us n

Comment: this sum can not expressed by the known elementary functions

Comment: Are you sure you want $\sum\limits_{m=0}^{n-1} \frac{2}{\color{red}{n} * (2n-2m-1)}$ ?

Comment: I would try to replace $m\to n-1-m$ and use [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141224/finite-sum-of-reciprocal-odd-integers)

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\sum_{m\ =\ 0}^{n - 1}{2 \over n\pars{2n - 2m - 1}}}
=-\,{1 \over n}\sum_{m\ =\ 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over m - n + 1/2}
\\[5mm]&=-\,{1 \over n}\sum_{m\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
\pars{{1 \over m - n + 1/2} - {1 \over m + 1/2}}
=-\sum_{m\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{m + 1/2}\pars{m - n + 1/2}}
\\[5mm]&=-\,{\Psi\pars{1/2} - \Psi\pars{1/2 - n}\over
1/2 - \pars{1/2 - n}}
={\Psi\pars{1/2 - n} - \Psi\pars{1/2} \over n}
\end{align}
where $\ds{\Psi}$ is the Digamma function.

> Moreover, $\ds{\Psi\pars{x} = H_{x - 1} - \gamma}$. $\ds{H_{x}}$ is the
>   [Harmonic Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Applications) and
>   $\ds{\gamma}$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. Then,

$$
\color{#66f}{\large%
\sum_{m\ =\ 0}^{n - 1}{2 \over n\pars{2n - 2m - 1}}}
=\color{#66f}{\large{H_{-1/2 - n} - H_{-1/2} \over n}}
$$

> Another useful relation is found with:

\begin{align}
\Psi\pars{\half - n} - \Psi\pars{\half}&=
\braces{\Psi\pars{\half + n} + \pi\cot\pars{\pi\bracks{n + \half}}}
-\bracks{-\gamma - 2\ln\pars{2}}
\\[5mm]&=\Psi\pars{{3 \over 2} + n} - {1 \over n + 1/2} + \gamma + 2\ln\pars{2}
\\[5mm]&=H_{n + 1/2} - {2 \over 2n + 1} + 2\ln\pars{2}
={\pars{2n + 1}\bracks{H_{n + 1/2} + 2\ln\pars{2}} - 2 \over 2n + 1} 
\end{align}

> such that

$$
\color{#66f}{\large%
\sum_{m\ =\ 0}^{n - 1}{2 \over n\pars{2n - 2m - 1}}}
=\color{#66f}{\large{\pars{2n + 1}\bracks{H_{n + 1/2} + 2\ln\pars{2}} - 2
\over n\pars{2n + 1}}}
$$