# Sum of terms of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-linear-algebra, harmonic-numbers

How to find the sum of the series stated bellow.
1/100 + 1/101 + 1/102 + ......+1/1000

I tried but it doesn't have any patterns to go with.

Please provide the approach for the above

Comment: Why do you think you can find it? In particular this sum looks pretty ugly according to [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2Fn+from+n%3D100+to+1000)

Comment: There is no general closed form. All you can find are good approximations. Particularly, you are looking for $H_{1000}-H_{99}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hoping that this could be of interest to you.*

I found [this paper](https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/245_07_JIPAM/245_07.pdf) very interesting since it shows several approximations of the harmonic numbers. In particular $$H_n\approx \log
   \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\gamma+\frac{5}{30 \left(2n+1\right)^2+{21}}$$ which is said to overestimate the result by $$\frac{2071}{12600 (2 n+1)^6}$$ This makes $$\sum_{i=a}^b\frac 1i=H_b-H_{a-1}\approx \log \left(\frac{2 b+1}{2 a-1}\right)+\frac{5}{30 (2 b+1)^2+21}-\frac{5}{30 (2 a-1)^2+21}$$ Using $b=1000$ and $a=100$ this leads to 
$$\sum_{k=100}^{1000} \frac{1}{k}\approx\log \left(\frac{2001}{199}\right)-\frac{198220000}{47569582236867}\approx \color{red}   {2.30809334291072}73$$ while the "exact" value would be $\approx \color{red} {2.3080933429107246}$

Computing the overestimate from the given formula, it is $\approx 2.65 \times 10^{-15}$ which matches the above values.

Comment: @JaumeOliverLafont. Thanks. In fact, when I saw, in aprevious answer of yours on this topic, I just wondered if there was anything new in the area of the asymptotics of harmonic numbers and, by pure luck, I found this paper. What I think to be very interesting are the upper and lower bounds provided  for the one in my answer.

Comment: Just to be sure, do you mean formula (1.14) in Theorem (1.7)?

Comment: @JaumeOliverLafont. Yes, this one. Cheers.

Comment: Maybe this correction that improves accuracy can be related to the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2301252/an-integral-and-series-for-log5-frac85

Comment: @JaumeOliverLafont. Yes, it is ! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As in [Summing Finitely Many Terms of Harmonic Series: $\sum_{k=a}^{b} \frac{1}{k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439177/summing-finitely-many-terms-of-harmonic-series-sum-k-ab-frac1k),
for an approximated result, we may use
$$ \sum_{k=a}^b \frac{1}{k} \approx \log\left(\frac{2b+1}{2a-1}\right) $$

to obtain

$$\sum_{k=100}^{1000} \frac{1}{k}\approx \log\left(\frac{2001}{199}\right) \approx 2.308097...$$

while first digits of the exact result are $2.308093...$

Comment: After looking at your different answers to this type of problems, I found an interesting paper(link given in my answer). Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The approximated value of the "Harmonic Number":
$$
H_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i} \approx ln(n)+\gamma+\frac{1}{2n}\\
\gamma=0.577
$$
The exact value of the requested sum:
$$
H_{1000}-H_{99}=2.30809334
$$