# Can't understand a step in summation

Tags: summation

> 5(b) $$\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)(2k+3)}=
> \frac{A}{2k-1}+\frac{B}{2k+1}+\frac{C}{2k+3}$$
> $$1=A(2k+1)(2k+3)+B(2k-1)(2k+3)+C(2k-1)(2k+1)$$
> $$\left.
> \begin{array}{ll}
> k=\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow& 1=8A\\
> k=-\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow& 1=-4B\\
> k=-\frac{3}{2}\Rightarrow& 8C=1\\
> \end{array}
> \right\}\Rightarrow
> \begin{array}{l}
> A=\frac18\\
> B=-\frac14\\
> C=\frac18\\
> \end{array}
> $$
> $$\frac18\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1}
> -\frac14\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k+1}
> +\frac18\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k+3}=
> $$
>
> > $$=\frac18\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1}
> > -\frac14\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac{1}{2k-1}
> > +\frac18\sum\limits_{k=3}^{n+2}\frac{1}{2k-1}=
> > $$
> > $$=\frac18\left(1+\frac13\right)
> > -\frac14\left(\frac13+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)
> > +\frac18\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+3}\right)=\ldots$$

Sorry for [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AqKC.jpg), only thing i have. Appreciate any help

Comment: I think the technique used here is **not** to evaluate the sum
$$
\sum \frac{1}{2k-1}
$$
(it would be a bit tricky ... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141224/finite-sum-of-reciprocal-odd-integers)
but to rather use the property
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} = \sum_{k=1}^n + \sum_{k=n+1}^{n+1}
$$
For example, the last term can be written as
$$
\sum_{k=3}^{n+2} = \sum_{k=1}^n + \sum_{k=n+1}^{n+2} - \sum_{k=2}^3
$$
So just juggle with the indices like that ...

Comment: Yup, there's no point evaluating the sum since it telescopes.

Comment: The problem is to find the infinite sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)(2k+3)}$. It was applied partial fractions decomposition. And the last two sums were re-indexed in order to have same denominator.